# Session Time Updation for New Tab Opening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

I have level 1 & level 2 menus in my application.

In session_start() method, I wrote code to add "session start time" in session variable.

Now when I open new tab for one of the Menus (from Level 1 or Level 2) I want to update the session start time.

Is it possible to do it ?

Currently I am using javascript & cookie mechanism for it. I want to handle this from server side.